# Pandas groupby sort to get rows for top two minimum values

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I want to groupby df["A"] and derive the values in df["B"] that correspond to the first two smallest values in df["C"]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                     'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B': ['cat', 'dog', 'rat', 'lion',
                     'bat', 'racoon', 'possum', 'deer'],
                   'C': [1, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4]})
```

I want the result to be:

```
   A    B_1     B_2
0  foo  cat     possum
1  bar  racoon  dog
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to do it?

Comment: Can't figure out how to go about it past df.groupby("A")

Comment: Is output correct? Plese check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

- `groupby` with [`nsmallest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nsmallest.html)
- reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)
- add `1` to columns names
- [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) last and `reset_index`

```
df1 = df.set_index('B')
        .groupby('A', sort=False)['C']
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.nsmallest(2).index))
        .unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns + 1
df1 = df1.add_prefix('B_').reset_index()
print (df1)
     A     B_1     B_2
0  foo     cat  possum
1  bar  racoon     dog
```

One row solution:

```
df1 = df.set_index('B')
        .groupby('A', sort=False)['C']
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.nsmallest(2).index, index =['B_1','B_2']))
        .unstack()
        .reset_index()
print (df1)
     A     B_1     B_2
0  foo     cat  possum
1  bar  racoon     dog
```

EDIT:

It works with `datetime` perfect too:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                     'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B': ['cat', 'dog', 'rat', 'lion',
                     'bat', 'racoon', 'possum', 'deer'],
                   'C': np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2017-02-18', 
                                                       periods=8), 
                                         size=8, replace=False)})
print (df)
     A       B          C
0  foo     cat 2017-02-19
1  bar     dog 2017-02-22
2  foo     rat 2017-02-23
3  bar    lion 2017-02-20
4  foo     bat 2017-02-24
5  bar  racoon 2017-02-21
6  foo  possum 2017-02-25
7  foo    deer 2017-02-18

print (df.dtypes)
A            object
B            object
C    datetime64[ns]

df1 = df.set_index('B')
        .groupby('A', sort=False)['C']
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.nsmallest(2).index, index =['B_1','B_2']))
        .unstack()
        .reset_index()
print (df1)
     A   B_1     B_2
0  foo  deer     cat
1  bar  lion  racoon
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works perfectly. How would one use nsmallest if column "C" was a datetime object?

Comment: I have to test it, get me a time. but idea is convert datetime to unix time and then it can works perfect.

Comment: I got it! Thanks so much.

Comment: Please check last edit. For me it works with datetimes perfectly, converting to unix time is not necessary.